# how do i change the top bar blur color change based on time? (blur my shell extension)

Tags: gnome, cron, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dbus

I have ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop with gnome 42.9. I use the whitesur theme to make my operating system look more similar to Macos by apple. I also use the"blur my shell" extension. how do I make the top bar blur color change based on the time using cron and d-bus?